# В чем различия выполнения кода в UI-потоке

Tags: java, android

Выполнять код UI-потоке в Android-приложении можно разными способами:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
        Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
    }
});
```

или

```
MainActivity.this.myView.post(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
        Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
    }
});
```

или

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask {
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
       Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
    }
}
```

В чем различия между этими способами?

Comment: первые два несколько бессмысленны с точки зрения асинхронности, так как такой код не будет выполняться параллельно, третий отличается тем, что код будет выполняться параллельно, а результат его работы будет передан в UI-поток через колбэк (то есть по событию завершения)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Разница в последовательности выполнения:

---

1) Выполнится **мгновенно** если запущено из UiThread, и будет поставлено в очередь на выполнение если запущено из параллельного потока.

```
//Пример для UiThread
Log.e("_","1");
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> Log.e("_","2")}});
Log.e("_","3");


//Вывод
1
2
3
```

---

2) Всегда будет поставлено в очередь на выполнение (не зависимо от потока).

```
//Пример
Log.e("_","1");
MainActivity.this.myView.post(() -> Log.e("_","2")}});
Log.e("_","3");

//Вывод
1    
3
2
```

---

3) Сначала запустит отдельный поток, а после его завершения поставит в очередь на выполнение.

```
//Пример
Log.e("_","1");
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
     Log.e("_","2");
   }
}.equals();
MainActivity.this.myView.post(() -> Log.e("_","3")}});
Log.e("_","4");

//Вывод
1
4
3
2
```